# Win 8.1 + Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

I have a sony vaio laptop, bought around june 2012 with Windows 7 pre-installed. My BIOS is a InsydeH20 rev 3.7.

I'm using Ubuntu alone for a long time now, I would like to install a dual-boot with Windows 8.1 alongside Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

First, I made a backup of all my files and formatted my hard drive. I turned on the UEFI option in my BIOS and I changed the partition table from MBR to GPT. Then, I installed Windows 8, I let it made all the partition it wanted. I upgraded it to Windows 8.1, then I turned off the fast boot option.

I installed Ubuntu on another partition and I created a last partition to share files between Windows and Ubuntu.

When I rebooted, I couldn't see Grub. It loaded right into Windows.. So I used boot-repair from my Ubuntu LiveUSB but that didn't change anything !

Here is the link from boot-repair :
http://paste.ubuntu.com/8008454/

So I would like to have Grub when my computer boots.

Also, I cannot turn off the secure boot option. There is no such thing in my BIOS and I can't see the UEFI setting in Windows. I mean when I'm [here](http://itsfoss.itsfoss.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Troubleshoot_Windows8_2.jpg) there is no UEFI firmware settings.

Hope this is well explained, let me know if you need more informations,
Antoine

Comment: This question may help - [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've read it all but I'm still stuck. I might have done something wrong, I will keep looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I used the link bellow and had complete success, including Grub options on every boot:

[Guide To Install Ubuntu 14.04 In Dual Boot Mode With Windows 8 Or 8.1 UEFI](http://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I've read this guide but it doesn't seem to work. I'll keep looking for a solution.